# how to assign labels to each token in my datafrmae?

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp

I want to change the structure of my data frame, I want to convert a data frame,

[image]

e.g first row is so

```
[Yes, it's annoying and cumbersome to separate your rubbish properly all the time., Three different bin bags stink away in the kitchen and have to be sorted into different wheelie bins., But still Germany produces way too much rubbish, and too many resources are lost when what actually should be separated and recycled is burnt., We Berliners should take the chance and become pioneers in waste separation!]
```

as you see in each row, column paragraph, I have a couple of sentences and in the column Label, I have corrpsp[edn label, I want to break assign to each token of sentences each  it is a label and it is Pos tags like this

```
[(Yes, UH, 0), (,, ,, 0), (it, PRP, 0), ('s, VBZ, 0), (annoying, JJ, 0), (and, CC, 0), (cumbersome, JJ, 0), (to, TO, 0), (separate, VB, 0), (your, PRP$, 0), (rubbish, NN, 0), (properly, RB, 0), (all, PDT, I0), (the, DT, 0), (time, NN, 0), (., ., 0),...]
```

i have kind  of done  to tokenized and assign pos tag using spacy

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
def mapTokenPos(l):
    tokenlist=[]
    for x in l:
        doc=nlp(x)
        a=[(token.text,token.tag_) for token in doc]
        tokenlist.append(a)
    return tokenlist
df["IOB"]=df["Paragraph"].apply(mapTokenPos)
```

but I do not know how to assign the labels to

Comment: Your question is unclear; it might help if you [edit] your question to include your sample input as text rather than a picture, and your expected output based on your input to make a [mcve] so that we can better understand.

Comment: done! I add a text, it might be now more cear